# Go with Glide - vendor doesnt work

Tags: go, glide-golang, govendor

I am using `go version go1.10.3 darwin/amd64` with `glide version v0.13.1`
Project is located at `/Users/robopuff/Development/GoRethink` and it's tree looks like this:

```
.
├── glide.lock
├── glide.yaml
├── main.go
├── rethinkdb_data
│   ├── 001fbc34-bd63-445f-8590-709ac7475294
│   ├── log_file
│   ├── metadata
│   └── tmp
└── vendor
    ├── github.com
    │   ├── cenkalti
    │   │   └── backoff
    │   ├── golang
    │   │   └── protobuf
    │   ├── hailocab
    │   │   └── go-hostpool
    │   ├── opentracing
    │   │   └── opentracing-go
    │   └── sirupsen
    │       └── logrus
    ├── golang.org
    │   └── x
    │       ├── crypto
    │       ├── net
    │       └── sys
    └── gopkg.in
        ├── fatih
        │   └── pool.v2
        └── gorethink
            └── gorethink.v4
```

After running `go run main.go` I am welcomed with an error

```
❯ go run main.go
main.go:7:2: cannot find package "gopkg.in/gorethink/gorethink.v4" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/gopkg.in/gorethink/gorethink.v4 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/robopuff/go/src/gopkg.in/gorethink/gorethink.v4 (from $GOPATH)
```

Shouldn't go compiler first of all look at *vendor*?

Comment: You said your project is located at `/Users/robopuff/Development/GoRethink` but per the error message, that's not in your GOPATH.

Comment: Even when I change to a `GOPATH=/Users/robopuff/Development/GoRethink go run main.go` result is the same

Comment: That's still invalid. GOPATH needs to contain a folder `src` which can contain your projects. A quick search for GOPATH should yield all the info you need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The proper answer for that one is to read through [Docs](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), especially [Workspaces](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces) and understand it.